# JDBCappender log4j2 and postgres error

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, log4j2

I'm facing some exception when trying to use JDBCAppender in log4j2. Here is what I get:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.isClosed()Z
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JDBCDatabaseManager.writeInternal(JDBCDatabaseManager.java:84)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseManager.write(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:159)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseAppender.append(AbstractDatabaseAppender.java:103)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:97)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:425)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:406)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:367)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:112)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.info(AbstractLogger.java:1032)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger$info.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at co.trucktrack.util.LoggerTest.test(LoggerTest.groovy:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Also you can find my log4j2.xml config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <JDBC name="dbAppender" tableName="_system.log" >
        <ConnectionFactory class="co.trucktrack.util.Log4jConnectionPool" method="getConnection" />
        <Column name="message" isUnicode="false" pattern="%message" />
    </JDBC>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="dbAppender"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

I wrote a test just to check what's going on and when I try to execute query manually it's working properly, but when i try to log something I'm facing the exception mentioned above. Looks like configuration part is not good or something. Can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh joy, after few days of digging I found the issue.

Well, I was using 2.0-rc1 version of log4j and after I switched it back to 2.0-beta9 it all worked smoothly. They obviously introduced some kind of bug in new version.

Comment: We've been moving away from using JDBC directly in Log4j2 due to the complexity of connection management and such. It is almost always easier to just use JNDI for the JDBC appender as the other two methods for getting a connection aren't as versatile as the JNDI method.

Comment: I have the same problem, switching from beta9 to 2.0. Did you solve the problem? What could be changed so c3p0 logging works again?

Comment: I simply reverted it to beta9 and we are using it to this day